# How to attach event handlers to collection items?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, catel

Hi all I have expendable lists in my form and I want to bind an on click effect to the items inside the expandable list. So far so good. I have managed to display the expandable correctly but I cant bind the double click. I am doing my project in MVVM Catel.

My XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsRoutes}}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Expander Header="{Binding Name}" MinHeight="50">
                    <ListBox>
                       <TextBlock Text="Something" >
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding OpenNewWindow}"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="Something" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Something" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Something" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Something" />
                    </ListBox>
                </Expander>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

and In the ModelView Class I have:

```
 public RouteViewModel(IMessageService messageService,
        IPleaseWaitService pleaseWaitService, IMapService mapService)
    {
       this.mapService = mapService;
       OpenNewWindow = new Command(CreateNewWindow);
    }

    public Command OpenNewWindow { get; private set; }
    //Method To Open the new window
    public void CreateNewWindow()
    {
        NewWindow.ShowNewWindowMap();
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with the [`UIElement.PreviewMouseDown` Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewmousedown(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: I recommend that you use IUIVisualizerService to show a window in MVVM, not showing windows directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the *DoubleClickToCommand* behavior:

https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/DoubleClickToCommand

The link contains information about the behavior and example on how to use it which I copied here below:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding PersonCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid>
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
          <catel:DoubleClickToCommand Command="{Binding ElementName=listBox, Path=DataContext.Edit}" />
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <Label Content="{Binding FirstName}" />
          <Label Content="{Binding MiddleName}" />
          <Label Content="{Binding LastName}" />
        </StackPanel>
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: No something else must be wrong with my code ... it is not showing up the new window

Comment: Well, the example works. Check out the examples repository for a real demo: github.com/catel/catel.examples